# error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'void (__cdecl *)(void)'

Tags: .net, callback, managed-c++

I have a plugin which defines a callback setter like this:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void set_callback(void (*fn)(void));
```

and plugin caller class  written in managed C++, which refers to the callback:

```
typedef void (CALLBACK* _set_callback)(void (*fnc)(void));

public ref class Caller {
    static void changeHandler(void);
}

void Caller::register() {
    _set_callback callback;
    callback((void (__cdecl *)(void))changeHandler);
}
```

Everything works fine until `changeHandler(void)` is defined as *static* method. 
How to change it to work with non-static method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** It appears I misunderstood the question. Given the current declaration of `set_callback`, you can't remove the `static` modifier -- that would make it a member function (which requires an object to operate upon) and you can't pass a member function pointer to a function that takes only a normal function pointer.

Comment: The sample I gave in the question does work - I just want to get rid of the `static` modifier.